# Factory Girl and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Here's my models :

```
Class Audition
  belongs_to :video
end

Class Video
  has_one :audition
end
```

and my factories :

```
Factory.define :video do |v|
  v.filename  {Sham.filename}
  v.video_url {Sham.url}
end

Factory.define :audition do |a|
  a.video     {|a| a.association(:video)}
  a.label     {Sham.label}
end
```

How could I create a video factory that have an audition,

I mean, be able to :

```
v = Factory.create(:video)
v.audition # I'd like this to be not nil !
```

Because I have an observer on my video that try to access the audition from the video object

I tried several things but I always end with a stack level too deep or audition nil.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's the case I would add the association into the other factory:

```
Factory.define :video do |v|
  v.filename                        {Sham.filename}
  v.video_url                       {Sham.url}
  v.audition                        {|v| v.association(:audition)}
end
```

Then you can do

```
v = Factory(:video) # This will now have an audition
a = v.audition # This should not be nil
```

and

```
a = Factory(:audition) # An audition without a video, if that's possible?
```

You can also override any association as needed when you create the factory in your tests, i.e:

```
v = Factory(:video, :audition => Factory(:audition))
v = Factory(:video, :audition => nil)
```

Hope what I've said makes sense and is true lol. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: P.s. I think you get a stack level too deep if you some how tell both models that have an association with the other one.

Comment: hmm that's exactly the problem but I was hoping with some conditional magic I could include it in both :-)

Your reply totally make sense,
Thanks,

Comment: After being stuck with trying to put a factory girl association in both sides of the association I finally gave up on it. And just put the association inside the "slave" model. In my specs when I need to create a "master" model, I still use the "slave" factory. For example: Factory.create(:slave).master.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 the answer is to use traits with after create actions on one of the factories, e.g.

```
    trait :with_audition do
      after :create do |video|
        create(:audition, video: video)
      end
    end
```