# FactoryGirl association model trouble: "SystemStackError: stack level too deep"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, RSpec-rails 2 and FactoryGirl. I am trying to state a Factory association model but I am in trouble.

I have a `factories/user.rb` file like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => User do
    attribute_1
    attribute_2
    ...

    association :account, :factory => :users_account, :method => :build, :email => 'foo@bar.com'
  end
end
```

and a `factories/users/account.rb` file like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :users_account, :class => Users::Account do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "foo#{n}@bar.com" }
    ...
  end
end
```

The above example works as expected in my spec files, but *if* in the `factory :users_account` statement I add the `association :user` code so to have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :users_account, :class => Users::Account do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "foo#{n}@bar.com" }
    ...
    association      :user
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
SystemStackError:
  stack level too deep
```

**How can I solve that problem so to access associated models from both sides\factories** (that is, in my spec files I would like to use RoR association model methods like `user.account` and `account.user`)**?**

P.S.: I read the [Factory Girl and has_one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238580/factory-girl-and-has-one) question and my case is very close to the case explained in the linked question. That is, I have an `has_one` association too (between `User` and `Users::Account` classes).

Comment: Just curious, you have a `User` and then you have a `Users::Account`, is that supposed to be plural or should it be `User::Account` or typo?

Comment: @kwon - It is not a typo. I have a `Users::Account` class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations), you can't just put both sides of the associations into the factories. You'll need to use their after callback to set an object(s) to return.

For instance, in the `factories/users/account.rb` file, you put something like

```
after(:build) do |user_account, evaluator|
    user_account.user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, :account=>user_account)
end
```

For has_many associations, you'll need to use their *_list functions.

```
after(:build) do |user_account, evaluator|
    user_account.users = FactoryGirl.build_list(:user, 5, :account=>user_account)
end
```

---

Note: I believe the example in the docs is a bit misleading it doesn't assign anything to the object. I believe it should be something like (note the assignment).

```
# the after(:create) yields two values; the user instance itself and the
# evaluator, which stores all values from the factory, including ignored
# attributes; `create_list`'s second argument is the number of records
# to create and we make sure the user is associated properly to the post
after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
  user.posts = FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Spyle's excellent answer (still working with Rails 5.2 and RSpec 3.8) will work for most associations. I had a use case where a factory needed to use 2 different factories (or different traits) for a single has_many association (ie. for a scope type method).

What I ended up coming up with was:

```
# To build user with posts of category == 'Special' and category == 'Regular'
after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
  array = []
  array.push(FactoryBot.create_list(:post, 1, category: 'Regular')
  array.push(FactoryBot.create_list(:post, 1, category: 'Special')
  user.posts = array.flatten
end
```

This allowed the user to have 1 post of category 'Regular' and 1 post of category 'Special.'