# find_failed_line error in rspec-core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am using `pry-rescue 1.4.2` and when my test fails it doesn't drop me into Pry, it just gives me this error:

```
UsersController
  DELETE #destroy
    when the inviter is being deleted and invited has not accepted invitation
WARNING: Tried to inspect exception outside of Pry::rescue{ }
      should confirm that the inviter_membership has a valid member_id (FAILED - 1)
WARNING: Tried to inspect exception outside of Pry::rescue{ }
      should successfullly destroy that user record (FAILED - 2)
```

And

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:263:in `find_failed_line': undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:244:in `read_failed_line'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:226:in `failure_lines'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:174:in `colorized_message_lines'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:272:in `formatted_message_and_backtrace'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:199:in `fully_formatted'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:110:in `block in fully_formatted_failed_examples'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:109:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:109:in `each_with_index'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/notifications.rb:109:in `fully_formatted_failed_examples'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:33:in `dump_failures'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:146:in `block in notify'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:145:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:145:in `notify'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:124:in `finish'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:64:in `report'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

These are the tests that it fails on:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  include ApplicationHelper
  include RelationshipConversions

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
    it "should find the correct user record"

    context "when the inviter is being deleted and invited has not accepted invitation" do
      before :each do
        user1 = create(:user, gender: 0)
        user2 = create(:user)
        member = create(:member, email: user2.email, first_name: user2.first_name, last_name: user2.last_name, bio: user2.bio, gender: user2.gender)
        membership = create(:membership, member: member, family_tree: user1.family_tree, inviter: user1, relation: "sister")
        connection = create(:connection, inviter_membership: membership)
        login_user
      end

      it "should confirm that the inviter_membership has a valid member_id" do
        expect(@user1.inviter_memberships.first.member?).to_be true
      end

      it "should successfullly destroy that user record" do
        delete :destroy, @user
        it { should respond_with(200) }
      end
    end
```

I thought it was the version of Ruby I was using so I upgraded to `ruby 2.2.3p173`.

Then I did a fresh `bundle install` and pulled all the latest versions of the gems I am using. Still no dice.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

Quick update when I execute my spec without using `rescue rspec /file/path/to/spec.rb`, it gives me a `stack level too deep` error. Specifically:

```
 1) UsersController DELETE #destroy when the inviter is being deleted and invited has not accepted invitation should confirm that the inviter_membership has a valid member_id
     Failure/Error: membership = create(:membership, member: member, family_tree: user1.family_tree, inviter: user1, relation: "sister")
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep

# /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:22:in `visit'
 # /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:11:in `visit'
 # /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:91:in `visit_Arel_Attribute'
 # /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:22:in `visit'
 # /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:11:in `visit'
 # /gems/arel-5.0.1.20140414130214/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:162:in `block in visit_Array'
```

And the same for the other failing test. It fails on the same `membership = create(:membership...)` line.

This is my `Memberships Factory`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :membership do
    family_tree
    association :inviter, factory: :user
    association :invited, factory: :user
    association :inviter_connection, factory: :connection
    association :invited_connection, factory: :connection
    relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    member
  end
end
```

What could be causing this?

**Edit 2**

We are making progress with the `after_create` callback in the Factory. But for more details on how the associations are setup, consider the following:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"
  has_one :inviter_connection, class_name: "Connection", foreign_key: "membership_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_one :invited_connection, class_name: "Connection", foreign_key: "invited_membership_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Connection:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "membership_id"
  belongs_to :invited_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "invited_membership_id"
  belongs_to :invited_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_user_id"
  belongs_to :inviter_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "inviter_user_id"

  validates :request_status, presence: true

  enum request_status: { pending: 0, accepted: 1, rejected: 2, removed: 3 }
end
```

Member:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships    
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :family_tree, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :inviter_memberships, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :invited_memberships, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "invited_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inviter_connections, class_name: "Connection", foreign_key: "inviter_user_id"
  has_many :invited_connections, class_name: "Connection", foreign_key: "invited_user_id"
end
```

Family Tree:

```
class FamilyTree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_members, through: :memberships, source: :invited, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_members, through: :memberships, source: :member, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the `include` statements outside of the `describe` block?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Just tried it and that doesn't fix it.

Comment: It looks like your `connection` has a `membership` that has a `connection` and so on, so an infinite loop is generated and the `stack level too deep` is raised

Comment: Give a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479031/factorygirl-association-model-trouble-systemstackerror-stack-level-too-deep

Comment: Good point. How would I fix that in this case? Not associate both of them in the declaration or remove an association in the Factory? In other words, how do I prevent the factory from creating a new record - which is what it seems to be doing - when I explicitly setup that association?

Comment: @Aguardientico Ahh...interesting. It seems like you are onto something. If you do up an answer along those lines, I will accept it if it works!

Comment: @marcamillion Please can you include the factories definitions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is related to associations between factories, `connection` factory has a `membership` and `membership` has a `connection`

If you remove the following lines of `membership` factory:

```
association :inviter_connection, factory: :connection
association :invited_connection, factory: :connection
```

and append the following:

```
after(:create) do |membership, evaluator|
  membership.inviter_connection = FactoryGirl.create(:connection, inviter_membership: membership)
  membership.invited_connection = FactoryGirl.create(:connection, invited_membership: membership)
end
```

It could be the solution. Please note that the same can happens with the other associations

Comment: Still getting the same error. I am going to attempt the same thing in my `connections` factory, but I am not sure why that would work because the connection end isn't creating an obviously recursive loop....I don't think.

Comment: The error is happening at `membership = create(:membership, member: member, family_tree: user1.family_tree, inviter: user1, relation: "sister")` so any of the following associations could be the issue: `invited`, `inviter_connection`, `invited_connection`, please try removing all associations and adding one by one, then when you got the one with the issue, try generating the `after(:create)` and test again

Comment: Does it matter what the actual association looks like? In terms of which side has a `belongs_to` and which side has either a `has_many` or `has_one`. I updated the question to reflect those associations.

Comment: Actually...I think I found the issue. The issue is the way the associations were done in my Factories. Given that `connection.rb` has the foreign_key for the respective membership relations, if I remove those `connection` associations in my `Memberships` Factory, it actually works just fine. So it seems that I setup my Factories incorrectly.  If you modify your answer to reflect this I will accept it. Thanks for everything!