# Rspec SystemStackError stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm developing an API using Ruby on Rails. I've created some specs for `posts_controller.rb` and I'm having this error while running the specs

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
./app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:10:in `show'
./spec/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my `posts_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe API::V1::PostsController do
  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @post = FactoryGirl.create :post
      get :show, id: @post.id
    end

    it "returns the information about a post on a hash" do
      post_response = json_response[:post]
      expect(post_response[:description]).to eql @post.description
    end

    it "has the user as a embeded object" do
      post_response = json_response[:post]
      expect(post_response[:user][:email]).to eql @post.user.email
    end

    it { expect(response.status).to eql 200 }
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

This is my `posts_controller.rb`

```
class API::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  .
  .
  .
```

Anybody have ideas to solve this problem ?

I realized that this is the line that causes the error, anyone know why? In `post_serializer.rb` file I have this

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :description, :price, :published
  has_one :user # this is the line !!!
end
```

If I remove this line the problem will be fixed, but anyone knows why ?

Comment: What does `json_response` do? Also, is there anything unusual about the factory?

Comment: `json_response` is a helper method that returns this: JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)

Comment: Do you have a `UserSerializer`? If so, please show it's contents.

Comment: @AndyWaite Yes

`
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :auth_token
  has_many :posts
end
`

Comment: Do you have `has_many :posts` in the user serializer?  If you have it, that and `has_one :user` in the post serializer is most probably the cause of the stack level too deep error.

Comment: show your factory_girl stab and model please

Comment: I suspect @RomanKovtunenko is on the right track.  Your `post` factory probably calls your `user` factory, which probably calls your `post` factory, which then calls your `user` factory, etc. ad infinitum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FactoryGirl association model trouble: "SystemStackError: stack level too deep"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479031/factorygirl-association-model-trouble-systemstackerror-stack-level-too-deep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference in your serialiser: the post tries to serialise its user, but the user serializer serializes the users posts, which then serialise the user etc.

There is a lengthy [github issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/211) about this issue in active_model_serializers 0.9.x. The issue is apparently fixed in 0.10, although that doesn't appear to be compatible with rails 3.x

A common technique appears to be to have 2 versions of the user serializer: one which includes posts and one which does not.